# Blazor some Javascript runs and some does not

Tags: javascript, blazor

I am new to web coding and have not had much experience with Javascript or Blazor.

I am working with this API called PictometryHost which brings overhead ortho images into an Iframe via Javascript.

I made a Javascript file and linked it in my _host.cshtml. Code shown Below:

```
var ipa = new PictometryHost('pictometry_ipa', 'http://website.com'); <----This works
ipa.ready = function () {
                                   <-----This does not appear to run
}
ipa.getLayers(function (result) {

    // Do something with the list of layers  <-----This does not appear to run
    // We can save them to reference later when we need to show or hide them.
    myLayers = result.layers;

});
ipa.getSearchServices(function (searchableLayers) {
                                                                        <-----This does not appear to run
    mySearchLayers = searchableLayers;
    for (j = 0; j < mySearchLayers.textSearchServices.length; j++) {
        if (mySearchLayers.textSearchServices[j].description == "Parcels") {
            var layerId = mySearchLayers.textSearchServices[j].id;
            for (i = 0; i < mySearchLayers.textSearchServices[j].fields.length; i++) {
                if (mySearchLayers.textSearchServices[j].fields[i].key == "mcontrolnumn") {
                    var fieldsKey = mySearchLayers.textSearchServices[j].fields[i].key; var query = {
                        searchString: "01059201",//PPN.value,
                        id: layerId,
                        fields: [fieldsKey]
                    };
                    ipa.searchByString(query);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
ipa.setLocation({
    y: 43.152139,       // Latitude                         <-----This does not appear to run
    x: -77.580298,      // Longitude
    zoom: 20            // Optional Zoom level
});

function setIframeAttribute(iFrame, urlSig) {

    var iframe = document.getElementById(iFrame);  <-----This runs called from index page with jsinterop
    iframe.setAttribute('src', urlSig);


}
```

I can initialize the Pictometry host and I can see it if I do a dir(window) in chrome I can see the ipa variable.

However, when I try to use the handle to execute it's methods as far as I can tell does not appear to run.

For example if I were to try to insert say console.log("Is this thing on?"); anywhere inside those ipa methods, I do not get a console output in the chrome browser. If I make a global variable var HasItRun = "No"; then inside any of the methods change HasItRun = "Yes"; HasItRun is always No at runtime.

I am sure there is something very basic I do not understand. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be fabulous!

Comment: Hi. Are you calling the code through Blazor JsInterop or are you expecting the Javascript to run as soon as the page has loaded?

Comment: Both, the function call setIframeAttribute is called by JsInterop in the onafterasync task event

The rest of it I want to just run in the body tag of the the html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is helpful to anyone. I had to nest the ipa methods inside the ipa.ready function. They were outside of the ipa.ready brackets and so they just didnt execute.

I also just ran my entire javascript file from the onafterasync task event instead of linking it in my host.cshtml file and having it run that way.

Now my Javascript file looks like this.

```
function setIframeAttribute(iFrame, urlSig, ipaLoadURL) {

    var ipa = new PictometryHost(iFrame, ipaLoadURL);

    ipa.ready = function () {
        
        ipa.addListener('location', function (lat, lon) {
            alert(lat + " : " + lon);
        });
        ipa.getLayers(function (result) {

            // Do something with the list of layers  <-----This does not appear to run
            // We can save them to reference later when we need to show or hide them.
            myLayers = result.layers;
            // Run the following to turn on the layers that were on when getLayers was called:

            // If there are some layers...
            if (myLayers.length > 0) {

                // Go through each layer
                for (var i = 0; i < myLayers.length; i++) {

                    // For each layer, determine if it was visible when this was saved,
                    // and if it was turn the layer on.
                    var layerState = myLayers[i];

                    // Layer was visible, turn it on
                    if (layerState.visible === true) {
                        ipa.showLayer({
                            id: layerState.id
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
       
        ipa.getSearchServices(function (searchableLayers) {
            mySearchLayers = searchableLayers;
            console.log(mySearchLayers);
            for (j = 0; j < mySearchLayers.textSearchServices.length; j++) {
                if (mySearchLayers.textSearchServices[j].description == "Parcels") {
                    var layerId = mySearchLayers.textSearchServices[j].id;
                    for (i = 0; i < mySearchLayers.textSearchServices[j].fields.length; i++) {
                        if (mySearchLayers.textSearchServices[j].fields[i].key == "mcontrolnumn") {
                            var fieldsKey = mySearchLayers.textSearchServices[j].fields[i].key; var query = {
                                searchString: "01059201",//PPN.value,
                                id: layerId,
                                fields: [fieldsKey]
                            };
                            ipa.searchByString(query);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    

    var iframe = document.getElementById(iFrame);
    iframe.setAttribute('src', urlSig);


}
```